# Problem implementing a dynamically-sized array

Tags: c++

I'm writing an implementation of a dynamically-sized array. The code compiles without errors, but the array elements don't get copied properly. They seem to just get erased (overwritten with 0's). Trying to call a getter on an array element causes a segfault.

The array holds pointers to some basic class objects; this is the main difference between my code and the examples I looked up.

This is the function:

```
// Pointer to array of pointers
SomeClass** mainArray = new SomeClass[1];
int numItems = 0;

void AddItemDynamic(SomeClass* newVal) {
    SomeClass** tempArray = new SomeClass*[numItems+1];
    // Copying pointers to bigger array
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems - 1; i++) {
        tempArray[i] = mainArray[i];
    }

    numItems++;
    // Adding the new value
    tempArray[numItems] = newVal;

    delete [] mainArray;
    mainArray = tempArray;
}
```

The code should copy the array elements over, then reassign the pointer to the newly created array. Instead, the pointer seems to be set to something else.

Comment: `SomeClass** mainArray = new SomeClass[1];` What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Why would you not use a vector?

Comment: Why are you creating an array of pointers instead of a normal array?

Comment: Implementing an exception safe and robust dynamic container is harder than you'd think. Luckily, the standard library provides `std::vector`, `std::deque` and other containers which are thoroughly tested and optimized.

Comment: As mentioned by others, there are already "dynamic arrays" in the C++ standard library, so use this only for the exercise or assignment, learn from it, and then throw it away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the current array have `numItems` element in them, then the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < numItems - 1; i++)
```

will copy one *less* than `numItems` elements.

And when you add the new element, you go out of bounds of the new array, because you increase `numItems` to early.

So two off-by-one errors in the same function, one in each direction.

And as mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561757/problem-implementing-a-dynamically-sized-array#comment97823519_55561893) (thanks Ayxan) the first off-by-one error will mean that the first ***two*** times you call this function, the copying loop won't happen. That's actually good when doing it the first time as then there's nothing to copy, but the second time there should be something to copy and yet the loop (currently) won't run.

Comment: And considering `numItems` is initialized with zero, it probably becomes negative and the loop body is skipped all-together. Hence all values in the array are zero.

Comment: Thank you for the clear response, this is exactly what was wrong. The result of copy-pasting code without reading over it properly; lesson learned.